# Allow Microsoft accounts to be optional without Group Policy?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, group-policy

I am trying to use the Windows 8.1 mail client without using a Microsoft account, and I've located [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pauljones/archive/2013/10/07/windows-8-1-mail-app-without-microsoft-account.aspx) to find out how. The instructions Microsoft provides involves the use of Group Policy to make Microsoft accounts optional. Thing is, I don't have that on my computer since it requires Windows 8.1 Pro. I am using Windows 8.1 (Core).

If possible, how can I allow Microsoft accounts to be optional on Windows 8.1 (Core) without shelling out the cash for a Pro pack?

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I figured it out, with the aid of the [Group Policy Settings Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250).

In the Registry Editor (regedit.exe), navigate to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Once you get there, right click on the right pane to create a new DWORD value called **MSAOptional**. When that's created, double click the MSAOptional value and change its value data to 1.

Now you shouldn't need to use a Microsoft account for the mail client or other Windows Store apps.

Comment: If I may ask, how did you proceed from there?  I tried a couple of other e-mail accounts: my work account and a gmail account, and it keeps telling me the info I have entered is wrong.